# What had happend to Trimpath Junction Javascript Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, frameworks

I've been desperately searching for a Javascript MVC framework to create rich client side applications with a Rails backend and I come across [junction framework](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/). It highly appeals to me due to its similarity with rails and offline capabilities. but unfortunately it has not been actively maintained for a long time.

I just wanted to know if the project still alive or I should look where else for a viable solution.

I know about sproutecore and cappuccino and I'm taking a close eye on them and their development process. But I'm really reluctant to learn something like a new language for this manner. In fact cappuccino using objectiveJ which is literally a new language running inside javascript.

IMHO, the killer framework would be something similar to Rails in structure, (as rails has already proved itself as a de facto structure for frameworks and has been ported to a lot of other frameworks) and uses jQuery to work with the dom and perform ajax calls. I still couldn't find it.

Comment: Hrm.... Rails killer framework....

Comment: Another similar framework: http://www.javascriptmvc.com/ - Highly compatible with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is still actively being developed.

I've been using Trimpath quite extensively myself lately and I didn't miss any features.
I sure hope it's still being developed but it's a great tool and really reduces development time.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for junction on the web and as far as I can tell the project is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ejscript: http://ejscript.org/products/ejs/webFramework.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a dev on Ejscript. The project not dead, just very focussed on embedded.